# Remove note of GCC ABI change

Tags: gcc, g++

When I compile my program with GCC 4.7 I get the following note:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward/binders.h:167:5: note: the ABI of passing structure with complex float member has changed in GCC 4.4 here
```

Is there any way to get rid of it? I tried to google it, but all I find is the GCC source code line that prints the note string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the option `-Wno-psabi` to GCC.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note: the ABI of passing structure with complex float member has changed in GCC 4.4
```

for the following line of code:

```
indices.push_back(make_pair(centreIndex,centre));
```

where centreIndex is an integer and centre is a complex float.

To get rid of the error message I changed the code to:

```
indices.push_back(pair<int,complex<float> >(centreIndex,centre));
```

I think this is a better way of doing it because make_pair is just a wrapper for this more direct way of creating a pair.