# Parameter passing for argument when C++17 is enabled changed to match C++14

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, c++14, compiler-warnings

I have a minimal reproducible example for the issue [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zeca9rTMY).

It generates the following note on Linux ARM 64-bit GCC 11.2 compiler.

```
<source>: In function 'void a(Color)':
<source>:19:6: note: parameter passing for argument of type 'Color' when C++17 is enabled changed to match C++14 in GCC 10.1
   19 | void a(Color c) {
      |      ^
Compiler returned: 0
```

Can someone explain the reason and **why you need to**:

1. Inherit a base class
2. Use defaulted copy constructor.

in order **to produce the note**.

How worried should I be about this?

Code in the link above for reference.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class C {};

// Must inherit to produce the note mentioned below.
class Color : C {
public:
    double x={1.0}, y={2.0}, z={3.0};
    Color() = default;

    // Copy constructor.
    // Default - gives note: parameter passing for argument of type 'rgb_color' when C++17 is enabled changed to match C++14 in GCC 10.1 warning.
    Color(const Color& other) = default;
    
    // Explicit - does NOT give the note
    //Color(const Color& other): C(other),x(other.x),y(other.y),z(other.z){}
};

void a(Color c) {
    std::cout << c.x;
}

int main (){
    Color c{};
    a(c);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is something ABI-related...

Comment: Dupe: [How can I suppress certain ABI change notes (embedded C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052105/how-can-i-suppress-certain-abi-change-notes-embedded-c) and [What does the gcc warning "project parameter passing for X changed in GCC 7.1" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149323/what-does-the-gcc-warning-project-parameter-passing-for-x-changed-in-gcc-7-1-m)

Comment: It addresses a bug in GCC < 10.1. The actual ABI as implemented by the compiler used to be buggy (different from what the ABI specification defines). This creates binary incompatibility. You should be worried if some of your code is compiled with the older GCC in C++17 mode.

Comment: The other question deals with trying to switch the warning off whereas I want to understand the reason. Plus it is unanswered anyways.

Comment: The issue is the same. You ask *"How worried should I be about this?"* and the question there says "Please correct my understanding if I am wrong, but *I don't think I need to pay any attention to the note* becaus...". That is, you shouldn't be worried about this.

Comment: Are you also using GCC 10.1 or earlier in your project?

Comment: No, we use GCC 11.2 across our project but users of it might not.